# Differentiation under the integral sign to evaluate Laplace transform of $x^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to derive the the Laplace transformation of $x^n$ using Feynman's trick, but I cannot see how the result can generalise to a larger domain of $n$. I believe the domain should be any $n$ that is not a negative integer(per gamma function). I do as follows,
$$\mathcal{L}\{x^n\}=I(s)=\int^{\infty}_0e^{-sx}x^ndx$$
$$I(s)=(-1)^n\int^{\infty}_0\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}(e^{-sx})dx=(-1)^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}(\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-sx}dx)=(-1)^n\frac{\partial^n}{\partial s^n}(\frac{1}{s})$$

At this point, everything seems standard, however to continue, I see no other way than to assume $n$ is an integer,
$$I(s)=(-1)^n \frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)(-4)...(-n)}{s^{n+1}}=\frac{n!}{s^{n+1}}$$
This leaves me with the factorial operator instead of the desired gamma operator found in the standard result. How can I get from here to, $I(s)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$?

Comment: "I see no other way than to assume $n$ is an integer": of course, you are taking the $n^{th}$ derivative.

Answer (score 2):

With $t:=sx$,

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-sx}x^ndx=\frac1{s^{n+1}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^ndt=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)}{s^{n+1}}$$ *by definition*.